# shell cron job to run a php file

Tags: php, cron

I need to create a cron job where I only have shell access. I know how to do it with cPanel, but this is on 1and1 server so I must use shell.

I got to the part where I add a new cron job in the crontab as per [1and1 FAQ](http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/cron_jobs/3.html), but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because the cron job isn't running at all.

This is what I'd normally put in cPanel:

```
0 8 * * 1 wget 'http://my_www_domain/googlefroogle.php?feed=fy_uy_tp&key=XXXXX3f7d1'
```

This is what I have in my crontab now:

```
0 8 * * 1 /usr/local/bin/php /homepages/XX/XXXXXXX/htdocs/googlefroogle.php?feed=fy_uy_tp&key=XXXXX3f7d1
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? BTW, if I manually enter the URL in my browser, everything works fine so I'm sure the script is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these answers helped me do what I need so I ended up using the following php file which was called by the crontab:

```
$data = array('feed'=>'fy_uy_tp','key'=>'MY_KEY_HERE');
$url = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$fullurl = 'http://www.MYSITE.com/googlefroogle.php?'.$url;

$ch = curl_init($fullurl);
$fp = fopen("MY_LOG_FILE.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

In case anyone else needs something similar... Also, note that this requires php5, the http_build_query doesn't work on php4

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can use wget on a cronjob on any server, so you there should be no problem if you keep using it that way.

Now, the reason it doesn't work it's because you can send GET params to a PHP file that way. PHP handles command line in a different way. See [Using PHP from the command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).

So you must check if the php file is called from a url or from command line (it's easy, look at [php_sapi_name](http://mx.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)) and, if that's the case, get the parameters using the command line interface or define them in your script.

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    if ($argc != 3) {
        die(sprintf('Usage: %s <feed> <key>', $argv[0]));
    }

    $feed = $argv[1];
    $key = $argv[2];
}else{
    $feed = isset($_GET['feed']) ? $_GET['feed'] : null ;
    $key = isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : null ;
}
```

Now you have to call the script like this on your cronjob:

```
php -f file.php fy_uy_tp XXXXX3f7d1
```

What it does, is that if the script is running from command line, it gets the arguments as variables, if not, then it check for the GET parameters to exists and use them.

Comment: uhm... may I ask for some more help, please? I'm a total noob when it comes to shell so I have no idea how to do this or how I'm supposed to append these parameters to my file. Any chance you could give me more detailed instructions?

Comment: I updated my answer, but please red the documentation. In the "Usage" section of the command line docs, there's an example on how to pass arguments to a file called from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use your cPanel "command" in crontab manaed via shell. 
use

```
crontab -l
```

to list current cron jobs.

```
crontab -e
```

to edit crontab.You will need to install crontab manually on some minimal installations.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
*/0 */8 * * */1 /usr/local/bin/php -f /homepages/XX...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a file with parameters like that, because the shell is looking for a file named "file.php?param=value", not "file.php".

if the parameters are always the same, you can set them by force in the script:

```
<?php
    $_GET['feed'] = 'fy_uy_tp';
    $_GET['key']  = ...
    $_REQUEST = $_GET;

?>
```

and then check that the script doesn't need some other variable, such as $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or things like that.